# Not able to find wifi network and change brightness on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, brightness

I have dual booted my dell laptop.
I am facing unusual behaviour on ubuntu my wifi network doesnt show up and i am not able to change brightness .
Everything works fine on windows though.
What should i do?

Comment: What kernel are you using, in terminal use command `uname -a`  Also see if linux-image-extra is installed for that kernel, `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-extra`

Comment: Linux nehal-Inspiron-5559 4.8.0-49-generic #52~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 10:55:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux<br>
ii  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic          4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-49-generic          4.8.0-49.52~16.04.1                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy31's "comment" should be the correct answer. I am on an HP Pavillion on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.2, and recently upgraded the kernel to 4.8.0-53-generic from 4.8.0-52-generic, upon booting, I lost all networking and brightness was set to 100%, brightness control was missing from the menu and the keyboard's brightness was unusable.

After booting back on 4.8.0.52-generic, I noticed that the linux-image-extra package had not been installed for the -53 version, so I installed it manually, and rebooted. All was back to normal from that point.

The strange issue here is that I used the standard "software update" app to update the kernel, and it seems like it didn't install the extras package for some odd reason, hope this helps.